# Chisel code showing wrong output

Tags: for-loop, chisel

This is the code for byte selector

```
class Comp extends Module {
val io = IO(new Bundle {
val in = Input(UInt(25.W))
val out = Output(UInt(25.W))
val i = Input(UInt(4.W))
val out0   = Output(UInt(5.W))
val out1   = Output(UInt(5.W))

})


val r8 = Wire(UInt(5.W))
io.out := Reverse(io.in)
for (i <- 0 to 20 by 5)

{

io.out0 := io.out (i+4, i)


when(io.out0 === 31.U) {
r8 := 0.U            
}.elsewhen(io.out0 === 0.U) {
    r8 := 31.U
}.elsewhen(io.out0 === 17.U) {
    r8 := 14.U  
}.elsewhen(io.out0 === 14.U) {
    r8 := 17.U            
}.otherwise {
    r8 := 27.U            
}


io.out1 := r8
}
```

This only selects the byte `20 to 24` i.e. when `i = 20` and not the rest of the bytes. Everytime I get the output as 27 which is when the for loop selects the most significant 5 bits. Can somebody help?

Comment: Can you edit your code adding the declaration of io.out0 signal please ?

Comment: Ok, according to your full code, it's normal that only bytes 20 to 24 is selected.

Comment: Yes, but I want it to select 5 different bytes everytime. I can write it using `when` but that will make the code too long. Is it possible to shorten it with the `for` loop?

Answer (score 2):

The scala for loop is like GENERATE in VHDL, you have to see it as a multiple declaration of :

```
io.out0 := io.out (i+4, i)
```

You can see it as following code :

```
io.out0 := io.out (4, 0)
io.out0 := io.out (8, 5)
io.out0 := io.out (14, 10)
io.out0 := io.out (18, 15)
io.out0 := io.out (24, 20)
```

The symbol ':=' is a connection between signal. Each line of above code is seen as new connection erasing the old connection.

Then only the last connection will be really used.

To do the connections as you want, you have to change (I think) the declaration of *io.out* and use an index like following:

```
for ( i <- 0 to 20 by 5)
{
io.out(i) := io.out (i+4, i)
}
```

With io.out declared as a Vector (Vec())